# What is the ‘has list-id containing’ iCloud Mail rule?

Tags: icloud, mail-rules

[image: iCloud Mail Rule]

What is the “has list-id containing” drop down option mean, how do I use it, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

> a unique identifier for a mailing list regardless of the particular host that serves as the list processor at any given time.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2919

You can use this to perform an action for a specific mass email, such as a company's newsletter.

If you used the email address, that might change. `list-id` won't change.

You can find the `list-id` in the email header.